# How to re-direct CLIPS-JNI-JAVA output to a string

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, clips

I have made a CLIPS-JAVA project, with CLIPS JNI, calling the CLIPS from JAVA.

The CLIPS code contains some **printout** statements, which are directly being printed to the **Console of Eclipse IDE**.

However, I want this output to be caught by a string in Java, instead of printing to the Console output.

Answer (score 1):

In CLIPSJNI for CLIPS 6.4, you can capture the output using one of the built-in router classes.

```
public static void main(String args[])
  {  
   Environment clips;
   CaptureRouter theRouter;

   clips = new Environment();

   theRouter = new CaptureRouter(clips,new String [] { Router.STDOUT, 
                                                       Router.STDERR,
                                                       Router.STDWRN } );

   try
     {
      clips.build("(defrule hello => (println \"Hello World\"))");
      clips.reset();
      clips.run();
      System.out.println("Output: " + theRouter.getOutput());
      theRouter.clear();
     }
   catch (Exception e)
     {
     }

   clips.deleteRouter(theRouter);
  }
```